# how to invoke a Math class function method by string name

Tags: java, string, math, methods, invoke

hey i want to invoke a **Math class Method** by **String variable** conatining a method name of **Math class** i have tested the below code:-

```
String spfunc="sin";
Method m=Math.class.getMethod(spfunc,double.class);
m.invoke(Math.class, 3.0);
```

but it resturns an error like this:-

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at EquationSolver.solveEquation(EquationSolver.java:112)
at EquationSolver.substituteValue(EquationSolver.java:94)
at EquationSolver.main(EquationSolver.java:20)
```

please help me out how to achieve this

Comment: Could you post the entire stack trace of this error ?

Comment: this is the only error it shows

Comment: call _printStackTrace()_ on the Exception object.

Comment: So the Exception comes from line 112 of your code. The stack shows that the problem comes from an ArrayList index, not from _class.getMethod_ or _method.invoke_ .

Comment: thanks now it worked